# In OpenLayers, how can I take rotation into account in a post-render function?

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas, openlayers

I'm trying to draw an "inside out" circle. That is, filling the canvas with a color except for a circular area. I took [this example](https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/custom-circle-render.html) and [modified it a bit](https://codesandbox.io/s/inside-out-circle-ym9twf?file=/main.js:1642-1992); <strike>I was able to do what I wanted and it worked *almost* perfectly (while dragging, the new visible areas wouldn't get rendered right away with the filling color on top.)</strike>  I just realized my attempt never looks right on my phone, so that's even more confusing to me!

I tried to write a similar logic in a post-render function:

```js
tileLayer.on('postrender', function (event) {
  const ctx = event.context;
  const [x, y] = map.getPixelFromCoordinate(circleOrigin);
  const radius = 50 / view.getResolution();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.rect(0, 0, ...map.getSize());
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  ctx.fill();
});
```

This solves the problem of rendering the colored areas in time, but when I rotate it (this can be done with `Alt`+`Shift`+`Click & drag` on desktop) it doesn't do it from the origin/rotation I would expect.

Why does this happen? I've been trying to figure out in what ways the post-renderer function differs from the circle's style function. I suppose there's a translation/rotation offset in the canvas that I'm not taking into account. If so, what is it? What am I overlooking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to convert from map piuxel to context pixel using `getRenderPixel`, examples in
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-spy.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/magnify.html
https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/layer-swipe.html

The simplest solution for a whole map `ctx.rect` is to use the canvas size

```
tileLayer.on('postrender', function (event) {
  const ctx = event.context;
  const [x, y] = getRenderPixel(
    event,
    map.getPixelFromCoordinate(circleOrigin)
  );
  const radius = circleRadius / view.getResolution();

  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.arc(x, y, radius, 0, 2 * Math.PI, true);
  ctx.rect(0, 0, ctx.canvas.width, ctx.canvas.height);
  ctx.fillStyle = 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 0.5)';
  ctx.fill();
});
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/inside-out-circle-forked-w8r5j8?file=/main.js